# Creating an inventory system using ComboBox/UserForms

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I'm attempting to create an inventory system at my work as the only software we have as Excel.  Basically we have a Work order sheet that we enter the repairs as well as parts used on.  I made a code that would pull the inserted part numbers & descriptions out of the individual work orders to keep track of everything used, but my boss wants me to create a system that will allow us to start typing the name/part number of something and have it guess or fill in for us.  Hence where the combobox comes in.

I got It working up to a point.  The lists are populated with the part inventory (we have a master EXTNERAL file listing) but my issue is this:

When you click the "add part" of the user form, I can't figure out how to have the parts be added in a certain range on the Work Order.  All the tutorials I've been following [here](http://www.contextures.com/Excel-VBA-ComboBox-Lists.html) and [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm02.html) only have it set up to add the parts in order of the column.  Can anybody look at my (terrible, I'm sorry) coding and see if they can help?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim cPart As Range
Dim cNum As Range
Dim ws As Workbook
'Dim ComboBox1 As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Workbooks.Open("\\Capserver\iso maintenance\CAPS MASTER PARTS & PRICE LIST 2012.xls")
Windows("CAPS MASTER PARTS & PRICE LIST 2012.xls").Visible = False
'ws.Sheets("CAPS ORDER FORM").Range("Name") = Sheet1.ComboBox1

'ComboBox1.Clear
For Each cPart In ws.Sheets("CAPS ORDER FORM").Range("Name")
    With Me.cboPart
     .AddItem cPart.Value
    End With

Next cPart

For Each cNum In ws.Sheets("CAPS ORDER FORM").Range("Number")
    With Me.cboNum
     .AddItem cNum.Value
     .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cNum.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With

Next cNum

End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim lRow As Range
Dim lPart As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim something As Variant
Dim box As Object
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")


With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:a500")
Set lRow = .Find(What:="", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

'Set lRow = Range("A1")
'    If VBA.IsEmpty(lRow.Value) Then
'        MsgBox ("POOP!")
'    Else
'        Set box = lRow.End(xlDown)
'    End If

'lRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A33:A37")
'ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows,  (From tutorial, always returned lRow =     Nothing)
'    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row 1

lPart = Me.cboPart.ListIndex

'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.cboPart.Value) = "" Then
  Me.cboPart.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter a part name or number"
  Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
'  .Unprotect Password:="password"
  .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cboPart.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.cboPart.List(lPart, 1)
  .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.cboNum.Value
'  .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.txtQty.Value
'  .Protect Password:="password"
End With

'Combobox1.linkedcell=C4

'clear the data
Me.cboPart.Value = ""
Me.cboNum.Value = ""
Me.txtQty.Value = ""
Me.cboPart.SetFocus

End Sub



Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

The goal is to be able to click the "Add part" button and add multiple files and have it output to the work order (I think the range for the parts is A33:A55 or something similar)

I ALSO would like to know if there is a way to make BOTH the part name AND part numbers dependent in the UserForm depending on which one you enter?  Though that is a lower priority.

Comment: I fully understand that this is a question about Excel and that you've said that Excel is the only software you have.  That being said, this kind of problem is best solved with a database, not a spreadsheet.  I would highly recommend getting at least MS Access -- you'll have a much easier time creating an inventory system that way.

Comment: If you're filling up the range A1:A500 row-by-row then `Dim lRow as Long` and `lRow = Worksheets(1).Range("A501").end(xlUp).Row + 1`  lRow is then the row number of the first empty row in ColA (counting up from the bottom of the range)

Comment: Lokerim, I realize that something like MS Access would make my life much easier, but the company isn't interested/willing to spend any money on software; hence my attempt to streamline things a little bit.  
  
@Tim, what if I'm trying to fill a range that's only A33:A45?  I can't use that code because it assumes that after the end of the range is blank, which in my case is not true as that's the second half of our work order sheet.

Comment: Also Tim, I tried inputting your code into my cmd_AddClick section of the macro and it still just adds the data over and over into the same cell.

Do I not need an If statement to make it work?


Nevermind!! Got that to work, I just had the wrong worksheet reference :)

Comment: Sorry about the multi-posts.  Would edit but I guess there's a timeout on that.  I took your code and did a little playing and go it to work! `lRow = Worksheets(2).Range("A30", Range("A30")).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: As @lokerim says this is a trivial problem in MS Access. It costs about $150 - how much does JohnnyD cost per hour? Do they try to drive nails with a screwdriver?

Comment: @JohnnyD what progress have you made?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not 100% on what you are trying to do, and you may have some sections commented out that you may want to use (ie the combobox). Your 1row range is finding the next empty cell which I don't think you want to do. But as for how you would input the information into a range, you probably need to change your ws With statement:

```
   1row = 35 'or whatever row number
   For n =0 to CountOfItemsToAdd 'could also be done with a For Each statement
   'You will also need another for statement here to go through your part list
    With ws
     1row = 1row + (n*3)
     '  .Unprotect Password:="password" [you only need this if using passwords]
     .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cboPart.Value
     .Cells(lRow+1, 1).Value = Me.cboPart.List(lPart, 1)
     .Cells(lRow+2, 1).Value = Me.cboNum.Value
     '  .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
     .Cells(lRow+3, 1).Value = Me.txtQty.Value
     '  .Protect Password:="pasword"
```

But to awnser your specific question, you change the first value in the .Cells reference which is the row index, not the second number, which is the column index.